# Firebase Messaging in Flutter Upstream messages

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

I'm trying to configure Firebase Messaging in Flutter, but it seems that there is no implementation yet for the Upstream messages.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream

What I want to do is to add a reminder and notify the user after x time with a push notification.

Let me know if you guys have any other solution, or we should simply wait for Flutter and Firebase for Flutter to became stable.

Thanks
Alvin

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there is no implementation for upstream messaging in FlutterFire yet, we are working on filling out these features. However given your use case you may be able to do something like write the user's reminder to Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database then when you are ready to send push notifications you can use Cloud Functions for Firebase to send the messages to the required devices.

Comment: Hi thnx for the update. If you have any tutorial for that implementation would be grear.thnx

Comment: @AlvinKonda u can use this https://medium.com/@rajeshjr/flutter-firestore-push-notification-on-data-change-youtube-style-subscribing-notifications-one-to-b09654db19e0

Comment: thnx @RajeshJr. i will take a look